# I'm getting an indent error in Eclipse compiler, anyone have any ideas as to why?

Tags: python, tkinter, computer-science

I'm getting an indent error in my Eclipse compiler, I have marked the specific line below on for where the error is. Anyone have any idea on the fix? It's for an assignment at school and I have no idea on a fix and I'm at a complete, absolute loss. I would appreciate anyone's tips. "Write a GUI based program that simulates a simple pocket calculator. The GUI displays a single entry field for output (I would suggest to make it a read only field). It should present the user with 10 numeric buttons from 0 to 9 and seven function keys for +, -, *, /, C (C is for clearing the display), . (decimal point) and =. = is to calculate the correct answer. If there is an error like divide by zero the entry field should display ERR or Error. Values in the entry field will build a string that will be converted to a float for calculation." This is the assignment I have to complete.

````
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont # for convenience

expression = ""
# functions
def input_number(number, equation):

    global expression

# concatenation of string
    expression = expression + str(number)
    equation.set(expression)


def clear_input_field(equation):
    global expression
    expression = ""


# setting empty string in the input field
    equation.set("Enter the expression")



def evaluate(equation):
    global expression


# trying to evaluate the expression
    try:
        result = str(eval(expression))
        equation.set(result)
        expression = ""
    except:
        equation.set("Error: Divide by zero")
        expression = ""

def main():
    # creating main window
    tk = Tk()
# setting the title
    tk.title("Calculator")
# seting the size of window
    tk.geometry("570x500")
# varible class instantiation
    equation = StringVar()
# input field for the expression
    input_field = Entry(tk, textvariable=equation)
    input_field.place(height=100)

    input_field.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=200, ipady=10)

    equation.set("Enter the expression")

    myFont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
    input_field['font']=myFont

# creating buttons and placing them at respective positions
        _1 = Button(tk, text='1', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(1, equation), height=5, width=10) #I'm getting an error on this line
        _1['font'] = myFont
        _1.grid(row=2, column=0)
        _2 = Button(tk, text='2', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(2, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _2.grid(row=2, column=1)
        _3 = Button(tk, text='3', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(3, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _3.grid(row=2, column=2)
        _4 = Button(tk, text='4', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(4, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _4.grid(row=3, column=0)
        _5 = Button(tk, text='5', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(5, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _5.grid(row=3, column=1)
        _6 = Button(tk, text='6', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(6, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _6.grid(row=3, column=2)
        _7 = Button(tk, text='7', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(7, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _7.grid(row=4, column=0)
        _8 = Button(tk, text='8', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(8, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _8.grid(row=4, column=1)
        _9 = Button(tk, text='9', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(9, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _9.grid(row=4, column=2)
        _0 = Button(tk, text='0', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number(0, equation), height=5, width=10)
        _0.grid(row=5, column=0)
        plus = Button(tk, text='+', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number('+', equation), height=5, width=10)
        plus.grid(row=2, column=3)
        minus = Button(tk, text='-', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number('-', equation), height=5, width=10)
        minus.grid(row=3, column=3)
        multiply = Button(tk, text='*', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number('*', equation), height=5, width=10)
        multiply.grid(row=4, column=3)
        divide = Button(tk, text='/', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: input_number('/', equation), height=5, width=10)
        divide.grid(row=5, column=3)
        equal = Button(tk, text='=', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: evaluate(equation), height=5, width=10)
        equal.grid(row=5, column=2)
        _1['font'] = myFont
        _2['font'] = myFont
        _3['font'] = myFont
        _4['font'] = myFont
        _5['font'] = myFont
        _6['font'] = myFont
        _7['font'] = myFont
        _8['font'] = myFont
        _9['font'] = myFont
        _0['font'] = myFont

    plus['font'] = myFont
    minus['font'] = myFont
    multiply['font'] = myFont
    divide['font'] = myFont
    equal['font'] = myFont
    clear = Button(tk, text='Clear', fg='black', bg='red', bd=2, command=lambda: clear_input_field(equation), height=5, width=10)
    clear.grid(row=5, column=1)
    clear['font']=myFont
# showing the GUI continue
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()```
````

Comment: There's very clearly many lines that don't line up.

Comment: As a side note, you should store your buttons in an array rather than having 10 separate variables. Then you could do `for b in btns:` / `b['font'] = myFont`.

Comment: lines after `# creating buttons and placing them at respective positions` until `plus['font'] = myFont` have some redundant spaces (2 spaces).  Furthermore, `main()` must have (4 spaces) before it. These are not observed in your code, which are related to the intend error.

Answer (score 1):

The line you've highlighted, and the following lines, are indented by an extra step - make sure they line up with the line above, as they aren't inside another block (e.g a function or an if statement)